# How to Convert list into other list using entityframework

Tags: entity-framework

I have two model classes first one is "Ticket" and other is "ExpTicket" there is only one additional column/properties in ExpTicket and others properties are same in both lists. I extract the data from database in the form of ExpTicket list and then re-assign all column/properties to Ticket List except one additional column which does not exist in Ticket list.

But iam unable to assign data from "ExpTicket" list to "Ticket" list. If anyone can timely help I shall be very thankful. Following is the code which i need to convert From ExpTicket into "Ticket" List but failed. Please help.

```
var GetTicket = ticketRepository.ExpTicket(r => r.TicketId == TicketId).ToList();
List<Ticket> CTicket = GetTicket.ToList();
```

Comment: AutoMapper. Or inheritance (ExpTicket *is a* Ticket).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Can you please correct my code above??? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I have done with inheritance, but at first the child class giving error so I googled and write [NotMapped] above of the child class then working fine, So I just need to ask why we write [NotMapped] in child class or why it is important ???

Answer (score 1):

First you have:

```
var GetTicket = ticketRepository.ExpTicket(r => r.TicketId == TicketId).ToList();
```

Then make a query:

```
var CTickets = (from t in GetTicket
               select new Ticket{field1=t.field1,field2=t.field2...}).ToList();
```

Or just readjust your model to use TPT (Table per type, [Table per type code first](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
var CTickets = new List<Ticket>();
var ExpTicket = ticketRepository.Where(r => r.TicketId == TicketId);

foreach (var ticket in ExpTicket)
{
    CTickets.Add(new Ticket { TicketId = ticket.TicketId, ... and so on });
}

// CTickets is the new list of tickets
```

Comment: Thanks Ronald, Is there not any other better way, just like someone said about auto mapper, because the way you describe is adding each row one by one using loop, this is I think may not be a better way. Cannot we map only the matching column in both entities?  What you suggest???, Thanks.

Comment: @user3004110, yes auto-mapping tools like Automapper or ValueInjecter should be able to help you, but I do not think that you can escape having to go through a loop (or at least by way of some LINQ shortcut that i cannot think of now) because in essence you are trying to convert a list of items based from one form of model to another model.

Comment: @GertArnold recommended inheritance, which is logical. What you will do here is derive ExpTicket from Ticket, where Ticket will contain all the common attributes and ExpTicket will only contain that one extra column that you refer to. But this approach requires that you touch your entities, where if you are doing database-first approach this could prove tricky during model updates from the databse. In code-first approach you might have better control, but either way I really don't know so in my case I will personally lean on the safe side and not mess up the entities until I know better.

Comment: Thanks, I have done with inheritance, but at first the child class giving error so I googled and write [NotMapped] above of the child class then working fine, So I just need to ask why we write [NotMapped] in child class or why it is important ???